# Gitlab CI runner configuration with cache on docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I can't seem to get the cache or the artifacts to carry over between jobs in gitlab CI.  I suspect it's something to do with my configuration, but I'm not sure what.  I'm running gitlab and gitlab-ci-multirunner, both in docker, using the following docker-compose config. I've left out the database config and some environment variables for brevity:

```
version: '2'

services:
  gitlab:
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:8.5.1
    links:
      - redis:redisio
      - postgresql:postgresql
    ports:
      - "10080:80"
      - "10022:22"
    environment:
      ...
    volumes:
      - gitlab_data:/home/git/data

  gitlab-ci-runner:
    restart: always
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner
    volumes:
      - gitlab_runner_config_data:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.crt:/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/ca.crt
      - /etc/ssh:/ssh
    links:
      - gitlab:gitlab

  redis:
    ...
  postgresql:
    ...


volumes:
  postgresql_data:
  redis_data:
  gitlab_data:
  gitlab_runner_config_data:
```

The runner configuration (`config.toml`) is:

```
concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
  name = "docker"
  url = <public gitlab url>/ci 
  token = <gitlab token>
  tls-ca-file = "/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/ca.crt"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    image = "docker-bash"
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
```

The `docker-bash` image referred to is just the official [docker:1.10](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) image with bash installed.

My build process consists of 3 steps:

1. Run `npm install` and the tests in the official [node:5](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) image.  For now, I've left this step out in order to test the deploy.
2. Build a docker image containing the code
3. Use ansible, via a custome built ansible docker image to deploy the built image to the production server.

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```
variables:
  FULL_IMAGE_TAG: deploy-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME:$CI_BUILD_ID-$CI_BUILD_REF
  IMAGE_FILE: deploy-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.tar.gz

cache:
  paths:
    - $IMAGE_FILE

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t $FULL_IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker save $FULL_IMAGE_TAG | gzip -cf - > $IMAGE_FILE
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $IMAGE_FILE

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: ansible-ssh
  script:
    - ls
    - ansible-playbook -e image_file=$IMAGE_FILE -e branch=$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME -e full_image_name=$FULL_IMAGE_TAG deploy-playbook.yml
  only:
    - develop
    - master
```

As you can see, the compressed docker image is referred to here both in the cache and artifacts sections, but is not actually available in the deploy step, where ansible is supposed to copy it to the remote machine.  I have tried including an `ls` command so check the folder contents and the file is clearly not there, but it is definitely built and I can download it from the gitlab UI.  Here is the log from the deploy job:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.0.4 (014aa8c)
Using Docker executor with image ansible-ssh ...
Pulling docker image ansible-ssh ...
WARNING: Cannot pull the latest version of image ansible-ssh : Error: image library/ansible-ssh not found
WARNING: Locally found image will be used instead.

Running on runner-59d43cf3-project-8-concurrent-0 via 381c2ea97744...
Fetching changes...
Removing artifacts.zip
Removing deploy-develop.tar.gz
HEAD is now at 6009bd0 test
Checking out 6009bd0f as develop...
HEAD is now at 6009bd0... test

$ ls
Dockerfile
deploy-playbook.yml
server
$ ansible-playbook -e image_file=$IMAGE_FILE -e branch=$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME -e full_image_name=$FULL_IMAGE_TAG deploy-playbook.yml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in deploy-playbook.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [deploy-host]

TASK [copy docker image] *******************************************************
task path: /builds/test/test/deploy-playbook.yml:44
fatal: [deploy-host]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "could not find src=/builds/test/test/deploy-develop.tar.gz"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @deploy-playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
deploy-host            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   


ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

I suspect that I am not setting up or using the runner correctly, but I can't find much in the documentation for anything beyond really simple cases and I don't know the tool well enough to know how it all fits together under the hood.

Comment: to be sure the steps are executing one after the other did you try to add        stages:
  - build
  - deploy

Comment: I did, but I can see the order they run in and it's fine.

Comment: What if you add the step `artifacts` to the `deploy` job? Or move it to below `cache` so it will affect all the jobs? The other question is, are you sure both `cache` and `artifacts` can point to the same path? I don't know, I'm just trying to help you out with the logic. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that gitlab doesn't support this yet. It's really weird because I can't see the value in either feature it you can't use them like this, but for now I'm manually caching what I need to a shared volume.

Answer (score 5):

Caching is not designed to pass files between stages of a build.

From the [doc](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html)

> cache : Define list of files that should be cached between subsequent
>   runs

I think what you need is in fact in progress : [WIP: Download build artifacts from previous stages and restore them in context of the build (Technology Preview)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/merge_requests/80)

Comment: Yes, that is what I want and is what I am trying to do, butit  is not working.  I have read both those links, and only added the cache to see if it would make a difference.  Despite what the documentation says though, the artifacts are not being restored in the second job.

Comment: Ok, maybe the semantics are debatable, but so what? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, update gitlab and gitlab runner, especially the 1.0.4 runner was quiet experimental.

Secondly in the cache definition, you should add a key see https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache-key

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  paths:
  - ..
```

From the https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runners-section, you should modify the `config.toml` and add a cache directory

cache_dir:

directory where build caches will be stored in context of selected executor (Locally, Docker, SSH). 
If the docker executor is used, this directory needs to be included in its volumes parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable artifacts in you `gitlab.rb`

```
gitlab_rails['artifacts_enabled'] = false
```

as described in the [Build Artifacts documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/build_artifacts/README.html)?

Answer (score -1):

Caching is a bit strange, but essentially:

`<dir path>` under cache are available between build jobs while `<dir path>` artifacts will allow you to use it inside the same job.

So:

```
cache:
  untracked: true
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - cache-dir/

setup:
  stage: setup
  [snip]
  artifacts:
    paths:
     - cache-dir/ #notice that the path above is the same
```

This will allow you to cache your files between each build job while allowing you to use that same cache *inside* the same job.

Don't forget to add the files you need to artifacts on each build step.